# How can I prove that $\partial\varphi\neq0$ implies $\bar\partial\partial\varphi>0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, harmonic-functions

Let $\Omega\subseteq\Bbb C$ open and  $\varphi:\Omega\to\Bbb R$ strongly subharmonic, $\varphi\in\mathcal{C}^2$ such that $\partial\varphi\neq0$.

My problem is to prove that
$\bar\partial\partial\varphi>0$.

My attempt: being $\varphi$ strongly subharmonic, by definition, there exists $\chi:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ with $\chi,\dot\chi,\ddot\chi>0$ such that $\psi:=\chi^{-1}\circ\varphi$ is subharmonic (that is exactly the definition of strongly subharmonic function I have to use).

From this we get $\varphi=\chi\circ\psi$, hence
$$
\partial\varphi=\dot\chi(\psi)\cdot\partial\psi\;\;,
$$
from which we know that $\partial\psi\neq0$. Then
$$
\bar\partial\partial\varphi=\ddot\chi(\psi)\cdot\bar\partial\psi\partial\psi+\dot\chi(\psi)\cdot\bar\partial\partial\psi\;\;.
$$
Next
$$
\partial\psi=\frac1{\dot\chi(\chi^{-1}(\varphi))}\partial\varphi=
\frac{\partial\varphi}{\dot\chi(\psi)}
$$
hence
$$
\bar\partial\partial\psi=\frac{\bar\partial\partial\varphi\cdot\dot\chi(\psi)-\frac{\ddot\chi(\psi)}{\dot\chi(\psi)}\bar\partial\varphi\partial\varphi}{[\dot\chi(\psi)]^2}
$$
and substituing this last one in the above expression for $\bar\partial\partial\varphi$ we obtain
$$
\bar\partial\partial\varphi=\ddot\chi(\psi)\cdot\bar\partial\psi\partial\psi+
\bar\partial\partial\varphi-\bar\partial\varphi\partial\varphi\frac{\ddot\chi(\psi)}{[\dot\chi(\psi)]^2}
$$
i.e.
$$
[\dot\chi(\psi)]^2\bar\partial\psi\partial\psi=
\bar\partial\varphi\partial\varphi
$$
which tells me only that $\bar\partial\varphi\partial\varphi
$ and $\bar\partial\varphi\partial\psi$ has same sign, but I can't go further.

Any help would be really appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: Would $\bar\partial\partial\phi\geq0$ suffice? This is easy to show.

Comment: My original problem is to show that $\bar\partial\partial\varphi>0$ and because of what I did, showing that $\bar\partial\varphi\partial\varphi>0$ would allow me to conclude

Comment: @ChristianBlatter: I totally edited my post! Can you help me please? Many thanks!

Comment: However: no, $\bar\partial\partial\varphi\ge0$ doesn't suffice, I have to show that under the given hypotesis we have $\bar\partial\partial\varphi>0$

Comment: What's your definition of *strongly subharmonic*? That $\varphi(z) - c|z|^2$ is subharmonic for some $c > 0$?

Comment: Take a look at the third line: that is the definition I have to use (however I'm going to edit, in order to make clear that is the definition).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that for (real-)differentiable $f\colon \Omega \to \mathbb{C}$, you have

$$\overline{\partial} f = \overline{\partial \overline{f}}.$$

Thus for $g \colon \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$, you have $\overline{\partial} g = \overline{\partial g}$, and hence

$$\overline{\partial}g \partial g = \lvert \partial g\rvert^2,$$

which gives you

$$\overline{\partial}\partial\varphi = \underbrace{\ddot{\chi}(\psi)}_{> 0}\cdot \lvert \partial\psi\rvert^2 + \underbrace{\dot{\chi}(\psi)}_{> 0}\cdot \underbrace{\overline{\partial}\partial \psi}_{\geqslant 0}.$$

Since $\partial\varphi = \dot{\chi}(\psi)\cdot \partial\psi$, the assumption $\partial\varphi \neq 0$ implies $\partial\psi \neq 0$ and hence $\lvert \partial\psi\rvert^2 > 0$, which shows that $\overline{\partial}\partial\varphi > 0$.

Comment: Many thanks Daniel, but why does $\bar\partial\partial\psi\ge0$?

Comment: $\overline{\partial}\partial\psi \geqslant 0$ because $\psi$ is subharmonic. A characterisation of (twice differentiable) subharmonic functions is that the Laplacian is non-negative, and $\Delta = 4\overline{\partial}\partial$. To see $\overline{\partial} f = \overline{\partial \overline{f}}$, use the definitions, $\partial f = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} - i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)$ and $\overline{\partial f} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)$. Split $f$ into its real and imaginary parts and expand.

Comment: It may be that you're using $\partial$ and $\overline{\partial}$ as differential operators producing differential forms, in that case you need to add $dz$ resp. $d\overline{z}$ in the appropriate places, that doesn't change anything substantial.

Comment: I've deleted my second question, I made immediately the simple computation. For the other question, you're right, I've misread it. However many many thanks, Daniel, really.

Comment: Now I read that we CAN'T use the differential characterization for $\psi$! How can we prove that $\bar\partial\partial\varphi>0$ without knowing that $\psi\in\mathcal{C}^2$ subharmonic iff $\bar\partial\partial\psi\geqslant0$? Have you got some idea?

Comment: If you can't _use_ it, then maybe it is legitimate to _prove_ it. The part that we need, that subharmonicity implies $\overline{\partial}\partial\psi \geqslant 0$, at least. How best to do it depends on what definition you work with and what else you know/can use about subharmonic functions. Maybe the following only uses known things: Suppose $\overline{\partial}\partial\psi(z_0) < 0$. Then since $\psi$ is $C^2$, that holds on a small disk $D = D_r(z_0)$. Let $h$ be the solution of the Dirichlet problem on that disk with boundary values $\psi(z)$.

Comment: Let $u = \psi - h$. Then you know $u = 0$ on the boundary, and $u \leqslant 0$ on $D$. By continuity, $u$ attains a minimum on $D$, say at $z_1$. Since $h$ is harmonic, you have $\Delta u(z_1) = \Delta \psi(z_1) < 0$, but that is impossible at a minimum.